# yodlee auth 402 error at oauthTechDiff.fastlinksb link

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, yodlee

I am working on yodlee aggregation api integration,when click on fastlink button iframe is open nd a url is hit
https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/linkAccount.fastlinksb.action
above url executed well status is 200 ok but getting error 402 on below url :
https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/oauthTechDiff.fastlinksb.do?oauth_error_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_error_code=402

don't know whats wrong, please help.

when i hit fastlink testdrive the headers are:

```
    Remote Address:64.14.19.74:443
Request URL:https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/userAccounts.fastlinksb.action?access_type=oauthdeeplink&cbLocation=cbLocation&displayMode=&oauth_callback=OOB&oauth_token=0406232215eb41f2966bbf6535e1817b&oauth_consumer_key=a458bdf184d34c0cab7ef7ffbb5f016b&c=csit_key_0%3As7vs61AA97QSLYOjnDouCT%2BbrCE%3D&l=access_type:cbLocation:displayMode:oauth_callback:oauth_token:oauth_consumer_key:u:o
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache,no-store
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 28 Sep 2015 11:34:52 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
P3P:CP='This site collects data required to provide the Service per the Privacy Policy of the financial institution'
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Unknown
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:Unknown
X-XSS-Protection:1
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=1ACB6E6D4EED261C1266A2F411828AE2; sfdcId=70100000000AVQPAA4; _mkto_trk=id:789-EJH-884&token:_mch-yodlee.com-1441860403119-11242; s_vi=[CS]v1|2AF74E7A051D0AAB-4000190BA004D84C[CE]; _gat_mtTracker=1; authtoken=5841_635790367759293670_73b2855a2573991536d668747457b36f59a3939841a575559813dc950c89ed62; _ga=GA1.2.1693074230.1441700770; __zlcmid=WcewC5oZikhqbL; tokensecret=f14639ac13324742a18d259fedb9abc5
Host:fastlink.yodlee.com
Referer:https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/linkAccount.fastlinksb.action?access_type=oauthdeeplink&oauth_callback=OOB&&oauth_consumer_key=a458bdf184d34c0cab7ef7ffbb5f016b&oauth_nonce=xoxQSGtir0K&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1443440091&oauth_token=0406232215eb41f2966bbf6535e1817b&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=Uy2ZgPaVU/LR5ukLVBuY83yarjo=
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
access_type:oauthdeeplink
cbLocation:cbLocation
displayMode:
oauth_callback:OOB
oauth_token:0406232215eb41f2966bbf6535e1817b
oauth_consumer_key:a458bdf184d34c0cab7ef7ffbb5f016b
c:csit_key_0:s7vs61AA97QSLYOjnDouCT+brCE=
l:access_type:cbLocation:displayMode:oauth_callback:oauth_token:oauth_consumer_key:u:o
```

And when i hit my project url and click on fastlink button then headers are

```
Remote Address:64.14.19.74:443
Request URL:https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/userAccounts.fastlinksb.action?access_type=oauthdeeplink&cbLocation=cbLocation&displayMode=&oauth_callback=OOB&oauth_token=4c69703f7fb04e75ab69e044bc9acb04&oauth_consumer_key=a458bdf184d34c0cab7ef7ffbb5f016b&c=csit_key_0%3AgnT0yGV8WkP49jPTkDwL1PwtAqs%3D&l=access_type:cbLocation:displayMode:oauth_callback:oauth_token:oauth_consumer_key:u:o
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
Response Headers
view source
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 28 Sep 2015 11:25:18 GMT
Location:https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/oauthTechDiff.fastlinksb.do?oauth_error_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_error_code=402
Server:Unknown
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=F69CD78440B1AEF299A010C0E5EE3A45; Path=/appscenter; Secure
Set-Cookie:tokensecret=123321; Version=1; Path=/; Secure
X-Powered-By:Unknown
X-XSS-Protection:1
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:fastlink.yodlee.com
Referer:https://fastlink.yodlee.com/appscenter/fastlinksb/linkAccount.fastlinksb.action?access_type=oauthdeeplink&oauth_callback=OOB&&oauth_consumer_key=a458bdf184d34c0cab7ef7ffbb5f016b&oauth_nonce=WrDxRR5kfhM&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1443439519&oauth_token=4c69703f7fb04e75ab69e044bc9acb04&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=eNBs6piveL9ACdPtSFyxomf4hTk=
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.99 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
access_type:oauthdeeplink
cbLocation:cbLocation
displayMode:
oauth_callback:OOB
oauth_token:4c69703f7fb04e75ab69e044bc9acb04
oauth_consumer_key:a458bdf184d34c0cab7ef7ffbb5f016b
c:csit_key_0:gnT0yGV8WkP49jPTkDwL1PwtAqs=
l:access_type:cbLocation:displayMode:oauth_callback:oauth_token:oauth_consumer_key:u:o
```

In my project i got 302 and auth 402 errors. Please help

Answer (score 0):

With the shared information, I assume you are trying to integrate Fastlink into your app/website.
The Oauth Error code you are getting as 402, this means required oauth param is missing from the request.
[Here](https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes/OAuth_Error_Codes) you can find different oauth error codes and what does each means.

Also, it would be great if you can have a look at the Fastlink integration guide present [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/FastLink_for_Aggregation/Yodlee_FastLink_Integration_Guide) and execute all the steps correctly.

If you still have questions or facing issues you can ping us on live chat present on developer.yodlee.com.